# Custom Knockoutjs binding for Twitter Bootstrap popover using template for html content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap popovers.  The popover requires that you set an attribute data-content for the popover's content (yes, you have to include data-html: true).  I'm using Knockoutjs foreach: binding to display a list of documents.  However, each document will have a popover item that needs to display html content built from the $data of that document.

I was hoping I could use ko.renderTemplate() inside a custom bindingHandler to render a template and push the rendered HTML into the data-content attribute but ko.renderTemplate() only seems to want to manipulate an element.

Is there any way to accomplish this.  Below is the code that I currently have working but I don't like it's brittleness.

**Working HTML**

```
            <div data-bind="foreach: govDocuments" >
            <div data-bind="css: { 'selected': Linked }" class="well well-small" style="padding:5px;width:300px;margin: 2px 0px;">
                    <b data-bind="text: DocumentTypeName"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <!-- This needs to remain before info-sign icon so that data is bound before popover binding -->
                    <div style="display: none;  padding: 5px; margin: 2px " class="well well-small">
                        <span data-bind="text: DocumentNumber"></span><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: IssueDate ? moment(IssueDate).format('DD MMM YYYY') : ''"></span> - 
                        <span data-bind="text: ExpirationDate ? moment(ExpirationDate).format('DD MMM YYYY') : ''"></span><br />
                        <span data-bindg="text: IssuingAuthority"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span  style="float:right">
                        <a href="#" class="icon icon-edit" title="Details" data-bind="visible: !$root.selectedImmigration()"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="icon icon-trash" title="Delete" data-bind="visible: !$root.selectedImmigration()"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="icon icon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-bind="popover: DocumentTypeName"></a>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Linked, visible: $root.selectedImmigration()"/>
                    </span>
                    <br />
                    <span data-bind="text: DocumentClass"></span>
                    <span data-bind="text: DocumentTypeCountryName"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Working Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var html = $(element).parent().siblings("div:hidden").html();
            $(element).attr("data-content", html);
            $(element).attr("data-title", valueAccessor() || "");
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(gov.documentViewModel, $("#government")[0]);
    gov.documentViewModel.activate();
});
```

Below is the idea of what I'd like to do:

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/html" id="popover-template">
                    <div style="display: none;  padding: 5px; margin: 2px " class="well well-small">
                        <span data-bind="text: DocumentNumber"></span><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: IssueDate ? moment(IssueDate).format('DD MMM YYYY') : ''"></span> - 
                        <span data-bind="text: ExpirationDate ? moment(ExpirationDate).format('DD MMM YYYY') : ''"></span><br />
                        <span data-bindg="text: IssuingAuthority"></span>
                    </div>
</script>
            <div data-bind="foreach: govDocuments" >
            <div data-bind="css: { 'selected': Linked }" class="well well-small" style="padding:5px;width:300px;margin: 2px 0px;">
                    <b data-bind="text: DocumentTypeName"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span  style="float:right">
                        <a href="#" class="icon icon-edit" title="Details" data-bind="visible: !$root.selectedImmigration()"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="icon icon-trash" title="Delete" data-bind="visible: !$root.selectedImmigration()"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="icon icon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-bind="popover: DocumentTypeName"></a>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Linked, visible: $root.selectedImmigration()"/>
                    </span>
                    <br />
                    <span data-bind="text: DocumentClass"></span>
                    <span data-bind="text: DocumentTypeCountryName"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var html = ko.renderTemplate("popover-template", viewModel() || {}, {}, element, 'replaceNode');
            $(element).attr("data-content", html);
            $(element).attr("data-title", valueAccessor() || "");
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(gov.documentViewModel, $("#government")[0]);
    gov.documentViewModel.activate();
});
```

Comment: What problems are you having with the second set of code that is making it not work?  Also if you created a jsfiddle you could probably get an answer much quicker.

Comment: The problem is that ko.renderTemplate() requires an element and wants to either replace or inject the html into that element.  I don't want either.  I need the html so that I can inject the HTML into an attribute of the <a> element instead.